# Question on the environment enumerate

Tags: enumerate

Is there a way to list like

```
1. hello \ \ \ \ \ 2. hello
3. hello \ \ \ \ \ 4. hello
5. hello \ \ \ \ \ 6. hello
```

with LaTeX ? (the \ are for the space).

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please explain that strange numbering a bit closer.! How big should that space be? How long could such a "hello" part become? What do you want to get with different line numbers in each "hello" part?

Comment: Actually, it doesn't matter. I juste want a listing of this form. Thank you.

Comment: It does matter a lot. Do you need such an arbitrary counting? Than use a table and do it manually. Do you want them to be split in the middle of the page or do you want to have a distance of `\\\\\\`? Do you want every two items to be on one line or could there be 2 long ones left and 4 short ones right? You left us with a lot of guessing. Please clarify. I do not even know, if you want to have a left left left right right right or left right left right left right structure here, as the numbering does not tell us a lot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apart from the weird counting, this could be done with the `tasks` package, for example.

If the way the counting does not really matter, it could be done with an `enumerate` which traverses down first, then uses the next column in a `multicols` environment.

If counting matters and the order is

1 2

3 4

5 6

then `tasks` should be used. However, with `\task[somethingdifferent]` the label could be set to `somethingdifferent`.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{book}
\usepackage[more]{tasks}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{multicols}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tasks}[counter-format={\bfseries tsk[1].}](2)
  \task item 1
  \task item 2
  \task item 3
  \task item 4
  \task item 5
  \task item 6
\end{tasks}

%Note: Not recommended!!!!
\begin{multicols}{2}
\begin{enumerate}[label={\bfseries\arabic*.}]
  \item A
  \item B
  \item C \setcounter{enumi}{1} % Counter value reset, now column
  \item D \addtocounter{enumi}{1}
  \item E \addtocounter{enumi}{1}
  \item F
\end{enumerate}
\end{multicols}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: perfect :-) Is it possible to have the count in bold ? i.e. **1.** hello  **2.** hello. Thank you

Comment: @idm: See the update